# Using Fork() and Pipe() to sum a file split to multiple child processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork

This is a cleaner final version of two previous question (ugly code; deleted by me).

I am using `pipe()` and `fork()` to sum a the contents of a file in child processes. To do this, I split the file up evenly depending on the amount of children:

1000 lines in the file => 2 child processes => first child sums lines 1-500; second child sums lines 501-1000 => send totals back to parent to sum each of their totals. Thus, the total of the whole file is found.

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numchild;
int fd[2*numchild][2]; //parent+child pipe
int i, j, len, fpos=0, val, count=0, total=0;
pid_t pid;
int nums = 1000;
FILE * file;

printf("How many children to use: ");
scanf("%d", &numchild);
printf("\nWill use %d child process(es).\n", numchild);

// create all pipes
for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    pipe(fd[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    if((pid = fork()) == 0) // child process
    {
        pid = getpid();

        // read from parent
        len = read(fd[i][0], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));
        if (len > 0)
        {
            file = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
            fseek (file, fpos, SEEK_SET);
            count = 0;
            total = 0;

            printf("Child(%d): Recieved position: %d\n", pid, fpos);

            // read from file starting at fpos
            // add values read to a total value
            while (count < (nums/numchild))
            {
                fscanf(file, "%i", &val);
                total += val;
                count++;
            }
            //write to parent
            write(fd[i+numchild][1], &total, sizeof(total));
            printf("Child(%d): Sent %d to parent.\n", pid, total);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Child(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
        }

        _exit;
    }

    // parent process
    pid = getpid();

    fpos = ((i*nums*5)/numchild); // 5 is the offset of the file values

    // write to child process
    printf("Parent(%d): Sending file position to child\n", pid);
    write(fd[i][1], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));

    // wait for child responce
    len = read(fd[i+numchild][0], &total, sizeof(total));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        printf("Parent(%d): Recieved %d from child.\n", pid, total);
        total += total;
        printf("Parent(%d): Total: %d\n", pid, total);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parent(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
    }
}
}
```

---

Output:

```
Will use 1 child process(es).
Parent(5497): Sending file position to child
Child(5498): Recieved position: 0
▒▒Child(5498): Sent 454019 to parent. //**yes this weird mark shows up**
Parent(5498): Sending file position to child
//hangs
```

.

```
Will use 2 child process(es).
Parent(5898): Sending file position to child
Child(5899): Recieved position: 0
▒|Child(5899): Sent 228601 to parent.
Parent(5899): Sending file position to child
//hangs
```

.

```
Will use 4 child process(es).
Parent(5904): Sending file position to child
Child(5905): Recieved position: 0
▒Child(5905): Sent 118304 to parent.
Parent(5905): Sending file position to child
//hangs
```

---

The code works fine for one child where I can see the sum come up, but it hangs and the parent never acknowledges the input from the child. Thus, if I use 2 children, I only see the sum from lines 1-500.  If I use 4 children, I only see the sum from lines 1-250.

What am I doing to hang up my program after the first child sends it's result back to the parent?

Is my code allowing the children to work at the same time?

---

Thanks for your help.

-Tom

Comment: With all this complication it is more likely to be a lot slower than using one process - the limiting factor being the speed at reading the file

Comment: @EdHeal  The goal is to see how my program run speed is affected when reading from files of very large size: 1000 lines, 10,000 lines, 100,000 lines, 1,000,000 lines, etc.

Comment: Why do you call `wait(NULL)` at the end of the per-child loop? That'll cause the loop to wait for child N before starting child N+1. Is the point not multiprocessing?

Comment: Why is your parent's per-child loop multiplying by two? `for (i=0; i<2*numchild; i++)`

Comment: @antiduh I did that originaly because there are two pipes per child process (Parent to Child, Child to Parent).  That has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

You're not initializing all of your pipes. For the sake of simplicity, lets assume you've got four children.

Then here, you allocate room for a total of 8 pipes, 16 file descriptors:

```
int fd[2*numchild][2]; //parent+child pipe
```

So far so good; a parent needs a dedicated pipe to write to the child, and vice versa for the child to write to the parent.

However, you don't initialize your pipes correctly:

```
for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    pipe(fd[i]);
}
```

That only initializes 8 file descriptors, not 16. You need to make that `for( i = 0; i < 2*numchild; i++ )`. That loop above has the effect of initializing:

```
fd[0][0]
fd[0][1]
fd[1][0]
fd[1][1]
fd[2][0]
fd[2][1]
fd[3][0]
fd[3][1]
```

Then, because you've not initialized your pipes correctly, you're reading and writing to the wrong pipes; specifically, you're probably reading and writing to standard out if you were lucky enough to have `fd` be initialized to all zeros.

This explains why it deadlocks - you're not reading to the pipe you're intending to write to. And this explains why you're getting weird output on standard out: you're writing your `fpos` to the wrong file descriptor because `fd` isn't completely initialized; you're writing `fpos` to file descriptor `0`, aka, standard out.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. It's working better now but I'm still running into issues. One issue is that my parent still tries to write to another child even when there is only one child to write to. The parent then gets the total and hangs.  Another is that when I try to add some code at the end `alltotal += total` I need to initialize an `int alltotal;`.  `int alltotal;` is fine, but when I make it `int alltotal = 0;`, i get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  Do you know where these errors might be coming from?  I'll update my code in the original post.

Comment: @Tawm - We fixed one problem - the initialization of your pipes. Another problem should be a brand new question, otherwise, it gets too confusing to try to track each problem and answer. So i'd edit your question back to what it was and then create a new question with your new problem. Just to get your started: have you looked at the core file? Make sure you post your analysis of your core file in your new question.

Comment: I will start a new question. But before, what do you mean by core file?

Comment: You said that you got this output: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. That means that your program did something illegal, and the operating system responded by writing the running state of your program to a core file. You can analyze this file using a debugger like gdb, thus letting you figure out why your program crashed.